# Entity Framework: One model for multiple tables with non identical structures

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have more than 50 data tables that have nearly identical structures. Some of the tables have additional columns. I'm developing an application to help me monitor and track changes to the data contained in these tables and only need to be able to read the data contained in them. I want to create an entity framework model that will work with all of the tables and give me access to all columns that exist.

As long as the model contains the subset of columns that exist is all of the tables my model works and I can dynamically switch between the tables with the same model. However I need accesses to the additional columns when they exist. When my model contains a column that doesn't exist in the table that I switch to I get an exception for an invalid column. Is there a way to have my model be the set of all columns and if the column doesn't exist in the context of a particular table handle it in a way that I still have access to the columns that exist? I know that using strait SQL I can do this quite easily but I'm curious is there is a way to do this with entity framework. Essentially I am looking for the equivalent of querying sys.columns to determine the structure of the table and then interact with the table based on knowing what columns exist from the sys.columns query.

Sample of issue:
The 50+ tables hold data from different counties. Some of there counties have included additional data, for instance a url link to an image or file. Thus I have an column that is a varchar that contains this link. Many of the counties don't supply this type of attribute and it isn't apart of the table in other counties. But there are 100 other reported attributes that are common between all tables. I realize a solution to this issue is to have all tables contain all possible columns. However in practice this has been hard to achieve due to frequent changes to provide more to our clients in certain counties.

Comment: it is better to have a sample what kind of differences do you have. You could have one big class/table with nullable columns or you could use inheritance

Answer (score 0):

From the `EF` prospective I do not know a solution but you can try something with an extension method like below:

```
public static DbRawSqlQuery<YourBaseModel> GetDataFromTable(this ApplicationDbContext context, string tableName)
{
     return context.Database.SqlQuery<YourBaseModel>("select * from " + tableName);
}
```

I think this will map only columns that exists in table with properties in your model.

This is not tested by the way but it can give you an idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework supports generating Table per Concrete type mapping, this lets you have a base class that contains all the shared columns, and derived classes for each specific table

https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines